# Convert UTC-time from column in MySQL to localtime (Sweden) in PHP output

Tags: php, html, mysql

I´m a totally newbie to PHP and I working on a very small project to visualize 
numberplates from our automatic licenceplate reader (Openalpr) to our forklifts to show witch lorrys who have arrived to the loadingzone (zone 2)

Everything runs on Ubuntu 16.04.1

The problem I have is that the timestamp of the numberplate read in the MySQL db is in UTC time format: `2018-04-05 08:56:33.320000` and I want it in Swedish localtime without the milliseconds (CET) eg: `2018-04-05 10:56:33`

How can I do that? All help is appreciated!!

My PHP code right now:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
try {
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $sql = 'SELECT epoch_time_start,
                best_plate
                FROM front_alprgroup
                ORDER BY epoch_time_start DESC LIMIT 30';
 $q = $pdo->query($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
 }
 ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lorrys in Zone 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Lorrys in Zone 2</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Lorry</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()): ?>
                    <tr>
                 <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['best_plate']) ?></td>
          <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['epoch_time_start']); ?></td>
           </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

"Fancy" HTML output on webserver:
[Lorrys in Zone 2 on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw47d.jpg)

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$dateTime = '2018-04-05 08:56:33.320000';
$utc = 'UTC';
$swedish = 'Europe/Stockholm';


$newDateTime = new DateTime($dateTime, new DateTimeZone($utc));
$newDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($swedish));
echo $newDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

So I updated your code block by adding the above code as a function, then use the function to display the dates in your loop.

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

function convertDate($dateTime){

$utc = 'UTC';
$swedish = 'Europe/Stockholm';

$newDateTime = new DateTime($dateTime, new DateTimeZone($utc));
$newDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($swedish));
return $newDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

}

try {
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $sql = 'SELECT epoch_time_start,
                best_plate
                FROM front_alprgroup
                ORDER BY epoch_time_start DESC LIMIT 30';
 $q = $pdo->query($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
 }
 ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lorrys in Zone 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Lorrys in Zone 2</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Lorry</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()): ?>
                    <tr>
                 <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['best_plate']) ?></td>
          <td><?php echo convertDate($row['epoch_time_start']); ?></td>
           </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah dang I was 44 seconds too slow! Goodjob